# Dimension of a certain space of symmetric functions: Part I

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, enumerative-combinatorics, partitions

Let $s_{\lambda}$ denote the [Schur polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial) associated to a partition $\lambda$. A partition $\lambda$ is called a $t$-core if none of its [hook lengths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula) are multiples of $t$.

> **QUESTION.** Consider the algebra generated by $s_\nu$ when $\nu$ is a $t$-core. What is the dimension of the space of symmetric functions of degree $n$ (i.e., the Hilbert function) of this algebra?

**Example.** (R P Stanley) For $t=2$ this is easy: the $2$-cores are the staircases, which are easy to show are algebraically independent. Thus the Hilbert series is
$$\large\prod_{j\geq 1}\frac1{1 - x^{\binom{j+1}2}}.$$
The sequence of coefficients are [listed on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A007294).

Comment: Well the number of $t$-regular partitions of $n$ is an upper bound.  It is not tight though, at least not for $t =2$ where they differ already for $n=5$.