# Dimension of a certain space of symmetric functions: Part II

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, enumerative-combinatorics, partitions

This is the second installment of [my earlier MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387090/dimension-of-a-certain-space-of-symmetric-functions).

Let $s_{\lambda}$ denote the [Schur polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial) associated to a partition $\lambda$. Denote the set of all [partitions with distinct parts](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html) by $\mathcal{Q}$, and let $\mathcal{O}$ be the set of all [partitions with odd parts](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/34/12/616.full.pdf).

> **QUESTION 1.** Consider the algebra generated by $s_\nu$ when $\nu\in\mathcal{Q}$. What is the dimension of the space of symmetric functions of degree $n$ (i.e., the Hilbert function) of this algebra?

> **QUESTION 2.** Consider the algebra generated by $s_\nu$ when $\nu\in\mathcal{O}$. What is the dimension of the space of symmetric functions of degree $n$ (i.e., the Hilbert function) of this algebra?

> **QUESTION 3.** It's [well-known](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/34/12/616.full.pdf) that there is a bijection between $\{\lambda\vdash n: \lambda\in\mathcal{Q}\}$ and $\{\mu\vdash n: \mu\in\mathcal{O}\}$. So, is there a relationship between the dimensions in **QUESTION 1** and in **QUESTION 2**?

Comment: Doesn't $\mathcal{Q}$ contain all one part partitions? And doesn't $\mathcal{O}$ contain all column partitions? It seems like these should both be the whole algebra.